# Comparing checksums from a directory and checksums from a store.txt file line by line to see if changes were made

Tags: bash, loops, for-loop

I am facing a problem with my bash script whereby I need to compare the checksums of my backup files from my /axa/backup/ directory and the store.txt file in which I have stored my checksums in to make sure that no changes have been made. I am required to use a for loop and a if-else loop but it seems to not work as I seldom use it.

This is my bash script that I have written:

```
#!/bin/bash
for md5sum in /sads/backup/*.tgz
do
  if [ "md5sum" = cat store.txt ]
  then 
     echo "no changes made in /sads/backup/*.tgz "
  else
     echo "Changes made in /sads/backup/*.tgz "
  fi
done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To generate MD5 checksums of all files:

```
find /sads/backup -type f -name '*.tgz' -exec md5sum {} + > checksums.txt
```

To verify that all files match their checksum:

```
if md5sum --check --status checksums.txt
then
    echo "No changes"
else
    echo "Changed files"
fi
```

A few notes:

- `md5sum` *will* fail if one of the files in `checksums.txt` is missing, but will *not* fail if a new file that is not in `checksums.txt` has been added.
- Remove `--status` if you want to see the status for each file:

  ```
  md5sum --check checksums.txt | grep --invert-match ': OK$'
  ```
- If you need to check files which may have been maliciously changed by someone else (not just accidentally changed by you), you want to use a more secure hashing algorithm. Simply replace `md5sum` with for example `sha256sum`.
- The above commands *do* handle weirdly named files:

  ```
  $ cd -- "$(mktemp --directory)"
  $ echo a > files/a
  $ echo $'a\nz' > $'files/a\nz'
  $ echo z > files/z
  $ find files -mindepth 1 -exec md5sum {} + > checksums.txt
  $ md5sum --check checksums.txt
  files/z: OK
  files/a
  z: OK
  files/a: OK
  $ echo fail > $'files/a\nz'
  $ md5sum --check checksums.txt
  files/z: OK
  files/a
  z: FAILED
  files/a: OK
  md5sum: WARNING: 1 computed checksum did NOT match
  ```